# Ajax Script wont run .. (AJAX+PHP)

Tags: php, ajax, dom, object

> Am trying to learn ajax and following is script but it wont run. Its
>   just a script to accept 2 user inputs and display them when submitted
>   in a div with ID info Following is the code for both files. Everything
>   looks fine but I don't get any results Kindly help. Thank you

- 1.php

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function makeRequestObject(){
  var xmlhttp=false;
  try{
      xmlhttp =  new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
  }
  catch(e){
      try{
          xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');                        
          } catch(E){
          xmlhttp = false;
          }               
  }
  if(!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined')
  {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
      return xmlhttp;                 
  }

  function showdata(){
  var xmlhttp = makeRequestObject();
  user=document.getElementById('user_name').value;
  email=document.getElementById('email_id').value;

  var file='2.php?username=';
  xmlhttp.open('GET',file+user+'&emailid='+email,true);

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
          if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                  var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
                  if(content){
                      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML=content;
                      }                   
              }           
      }
      xmlhttp.send();         
  }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="user_name" /> <br/>
      <label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email_id" /> <br/>
      <input type="button" onclick="showdata()" value="Submit" />
      <div id="info"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- 2.php

  ```
  <?php 
  echo "Welcome ".$_GET['username']." to our Shopping Mall <br/>";
  echo "Your email id is ".$_GET['emailid'];
  ?>
  ```

Comment: Define `Everything looks fine but I don't get any results`

Comment: Also, I highly recommend using jQuery or another modern library capable of doing AJAX, unless you have very good reasons not to.

Comment: you are using `getElementById` and not providing any `id` in input types

Comment: Well am new to ajax and am using a book to learn it and javascript looks ok but i don't if there is some mistake calling ActiveXObject..  basically its the same code from I tried.

Comment: Thanks @Hamza will do that as I get to see how ajax works.

Comment: You're probably using a fairly old book (my guess is 2006 or so) if that's the example code they give you. :)

Comment: Yes it is.. Suggest a good book to me to learn Jquery and AJAX? **HeadFirst** is good??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put id of element like this way:

Remove:

```
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="user_name" /> <br/>
<label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email_id" /> <br/>
```

Add:

```
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" /> <br/>
<label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email_id" id="email_id" /> <br/>
```